# Error using ElementTree to parse data from .config file

Tags: python-2.7, elementtree

Im trying to use ElementTree to get data from a .config file. The structure of this file is like this for example:

```
<userSettings>
        <AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="Username" serializeAs="String">
                <value>AAA</value>
            </setting>
```

My code is this:

```
import os, sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class Init():
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    rel_path = "app.config"
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path) 

    tree = ET.parse(abs_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    sites = root.iter('userSettings')
    for site in sites: 
        apps = site.findall('AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours.My.MySettings')
        for app in apps:
            print(''.join([site.get('Username'), app.get('value')]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = Init()
```

However, when I run this code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AAAA/Documents/Aptana/AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours/Main.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Init():
  File "/Users/AAA/Documents/Aptana/AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours/Main.py", line 16, in Init
    print(''.join([site.get('Username'), app.get('value')]))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found
```

What I'm I doing wrong the causes this error?

(My problem seems to be accessing the tree structure of my config.file correctly)

Comment: @perror I really don't understand why you would think this is a duplicate of that..

Comment: I agree, I misread your question. It seems that 'Username' might be of `NoneType` and that is the problem. Sorry.

Comment: @perror yeah, but I believe its because im not accessing the tree structure correctly, any help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change your code to:

```
print(''.join([app.get('name'), app.find('value').text]))
```

`app` is an [Element Object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) in this case `<setting>`. Using the `get` function you will get an attribute value by name (e.g. name, serializeAs), using the `find`
function you will get a subelement (e.g `<value>`).

Once you have `<value>` you can get the data inside with `text`

Note that `site` (`<AutotaskUpdateTicketEstimatedHours.My.MySettings>`) doesn't have any attributes, therefore you get `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!